# iOS 10 collectionView:prefetchItemsAt not called

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, ios10

I am trying out the new `collectionView:prefetchItemsAt` and `collectionView:cancelPrefetchingForItemsAt` methods of the `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` protocol, but neither of those are called. The delegate is set via interface builder (tried from code with the same result), deployment target is set to iOS 10, so in theory it should work. So my question is that am I missing something in order to make it work, or the mechanism is more sophisticated than I thought and the system doesn't felt that it should do the prefetching?

Comment: Is `UICollectionView` property called `prefetchingEnabled` set to `YES`? Just tried this case in Xcode 8.0 beta 4 - works as expected.

Comment: @RomanErmolov yes, it was set to `true`, but no effect. Just for the reference, I was using Swift

Comment: in theory, the language should not matter at all. I can make a guess that you don't have invisible cells - if all cells are on screen, this method doesnt called.

Comment: And last try: did you set `prefetchDataSource` property of `UICollectionView`?

Comment: Did you found solution? Seems collection view's prefetch is only works when your cells have fixed size. So bad.

Comment: It's not whether the item size is fixed or not (because prefetching works fine with both), but rather the non-zero `estimatedItemSize`.

Answer (score 12):

It may be that you are setting the estimatedItemSize in which case prefetching may not be called.
Source: Tried it out in a mini demo app.

Comment: you saved my day, Thanks

Comment: yes setting it to none seems to make the callback get called.

Comment: For me setting this on the CollectionView object on the storyboard solved it. What a weird side effect...

Answer (score 5):

Implement UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching interface in your ViewController:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching {

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      collectionView.delegate = self
      collectionView.dataSource = self
      collectionView.prefetchDataSource = self
   }
}
```

You have to check the collection view property is "isPrefetching" enabled. If it is not enabled set its value to true.

```
collectionView.isPrefetchingEnabled = true
```

Answer (score 2):

From [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/1771767-collectionview):

> The collection view does not call this method for cells it requires immediately, so your code must not rely on this method to load data

Answer (score 1):

Inherit from the protocol `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` in your `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching {
```

Set following delegates to your collection view in storyboard (see the attached image), or do so programmatically.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView.delegate = self
    collectionView.dataSource = self
    collectionView.prefetchDataSource = self
}
```

Refer to this example: https://github.com/Be-With-Viresh/CollectionViewWithPrefetch

[image: delegates hooked up in storyboard]

Answer (score 1):

**Flow Layout**

Setting estimated size to anything but `none` causes the default Flow Layout to not call the prefetch method for me. Here is a sample callback:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, prefetchItemsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
    print(indexPaths.map { $0.row })
}
```

Note setting this here, actually sets it on the implicitly created Flow Layout, not the actual `UICollectionView`:

[image]

This can be verified using Apple's Sample Code, changing it to anything other than `none` causes it to not call the delegate.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdatasourceprefetching/prefetching_collection_view_data

**Compositional Layout**

One another aspect, it can also work with Compositional Layouts since they don't have the `estimatedSize` property like a the default Flow Layout that is automatically created in IB. If you create a compositional layout, it will replace that default Flow Layout, so setting that property in IB will do nothing if you set a Compositional Layout.

Example of a Compositional Layout:

```
func createCompositionalLayout() -> UICollectionViewLayout {
    let itemSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
      widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
      heightDimension: .fractionalHeight(1.0)
    )
    let item = NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: itemSize)
    let groupSize = NSCollectionLayoutSize(
      widthDimension: .fractionalWidth(1.0),
      heightDimension: .fractionalWidth(1/5)
    )
    let group = NSCollectionLayoutGroup.horizontal(
      layoutSize: groupSize,
      subitem: item,
      count: 1
    )
    let section = NSCollectionLayoutSection(group: group)
    return UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout(section: section)
}
```

And set it like this:

```
collectionView.collectionViewLayout = createCompositionalLayout()
```

in the `viewDidLoad` delegate.

Doing it like this does allow the `prefetchItemsAt` method to get invoked.

Also have found that if the cell height is estimated on a Compositional Layout it does not work. Which sucks.

[UICollectionView: compositional layout disables prefetching?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62726919/uicollectionview-compositional-layout-disables-prefetching)

It seems that if any of your layoutSize objects have a estimated dimension, it bails out on prefetch.

```
    let size = NSCollectionLayoutSize(widthDimension: .estimated(104),
                                      heightDimension: .estimated(128))
    return NSCollectionLayoutItem(layoutSize: size)
```

Answer (score 0):

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

//add code to this func

> > > > > self.collectionView(collectionView, prefetchItemsAt: [indexPath])<<<<<

```
}
```