# UICollectionView Prefetch Data Source not called

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, prefetch

I have UICollectionView with multiple types of cells. I've set the prefetch datasource, implement datasource methods, but they are not called when user scrolls to bottom of UICollectionView. I've tried to investigate possible issues, but everything seems ok. 
I've found that my cell has ambiguous layout (not displayed in console, but in view debugger). Could this affect behaviour of prefetch datasource?

Comment: They are not called at all, or just for the bottom cells?

Comment: They are not called at all. I was playing with flow layout. When I set fixed item size (dropped autolayout) then Prefetch datasource was called. So my observation is that I have to solve autolayout ambiguity and then it should work ...

Comment: Maybe this will help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326210/ios-10-collectionviewprefetchitemsat-not-called/52896469#52896469

Answer (score 0):

just make sure You are no setting estimatedItemSize in Your UICollectionView