# UICollectionVIew Compositional Layout & DiffableDataSource, how to enable data prefetching?

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uikit, uicollectionviewcompositionallayout, uicollectionviewdiffabledatasource

How to enable data prefetching when using the new Compositional Layout & DiffableDataSource?

Before, we can achieve this by conforming a custom data source object, like,

`class CustomDataSource: NSObject, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching`

Now, the data source is the `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`, which only conforms to `UICollectionViewDataSource`.

One way is to extend it to conform to the prefetching protocol. However, due to the fact that it encapsulates protocol implementations of the DataSource into its higher level methods like `snapshots` and `apply`. I can't figure out how to extend it to conforms to the prefetching protocol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your implementation of `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` is set on a separate property of `UICollectionView` called `prefetchDataSource`. So you should not need to subclass `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1771768-prefetchdatasource

I can confirm that prefetching works when using a `UICollectionViewDiffableDataSource`. You will need to cache your prefetched data somewhere, and then access it from your `cellProvider` (or `UICollectionView.CellRegistration`)

For example, if your view controller implements `UICollectionViewDataSourcePrefetching` then you may have a line where you assign it as the `prefetchDataSource`:

```
myCollectionView.prefetchDataSource = self
```

Comment: Note that with Compositional Layout if you use `.estimated()` in a dimension of `NSCollectionLayoutSize` in your `UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout` then the prefetching data source is never called. I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working for me until I discovered that fact.

Comment: @DevinPitcher would you please share where you read such info.

Comment: @AhmedShendy it's been long enough I don't remember if I read it some where or discovered it on my own. This SO question describes the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/q/62726919/3067557.